# SQL query not showing any change in database

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a model in django where I want to enter some data using the query below. The query is running without any errors but the tuple isn't added in the database. What could be the reason for this?

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('C:\mysite\db.sqlite3')
cursor=conn.cursor()
query="INSERT INTO 'polls_finalscore' VALUES (1,'michel',22);"
result=cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you have executed your query you need to commit the transaction so add the below after `cursor.execute(...)`

```
conn.commit()
```